# Error en un ciclo FOR

Tags: php, laravel

Me gustaría poder hacer una consulta mediante un ciclo `for`, en la cual me cuente cuantos correos tengo registrados en mi tabla usuarios, 
tome el correo de mi primera fila de la tabla usuarios lo compare con mi tabla productos y si los correos concuerdan me devuelva un listado
con los artículos que tiene, y así con el segundo correo y dependiendo del número de correos que maneje se ejecute mi consulta, la cual 
pretendo mandar en forma de listado de artículos a cada usuario.

Tengo una consulta en mi controlador que me arroja los correos de mis usuarios

```
$nuevo = ContactoServicio::select('email')->get();

echo "correos" . $nuevo;
```

lo cual me devuelve esto en pantalla

> correo...[{"email":"armando@prueba.com"},{"email":"raul@prueba.com"},{"email":"gaby@prueba.com"}]

esta es mi ciclo for

```
$correos = ContactoServicio::select('email')->count();

for ($i=0; $i < $correos; $i++) { 

         $nuevo = ContactoServicio::select('email')->distinct('email')->get();

            echo "correo..." . $nuevo . ' ' ;

         }
```

pero este solo me imprime lo siguiente:

> correo...[{"email":"armando@prueba.com"},{"email":"raul@prueba.com"},{"email":"gaby@prueba.com"}]
>   correo...[{"email":"armando@prueba.com"},{"email":"raul@prueba.com"},{"email":"gaby@prueba.com"}]
>   correo...[{"email":"armando@prueba.com"},{"email":"raul@prueba.com"},{"email":"gaby@prueba.com"}]

En esta parte quisiera lograr que imprimiera

> correo...[{"email":"armando@prueba.com"}] 
>   correo...[{"email":"raul@prueba.com"}] 
>   correo...[{"email":"gaby@prueba.com"}]

y esta es mi consulta que quiero que se ejecute dependiendo de el correo que le mande

```
$consulta = LogHistorial::select('log_Historial.nombre','log_Historial.email','modelo.precio','marca.nombre_marca')
      ->join('modelo', 'log_Historial.id_modelo', '=', 'modelo.idmodelo')
      ->join('marca', 'modelo.id_marca', '=', 'marca.idmarca')
      ->where('vehiculo.status', '=', 'publicado')
      ->where('log_Historial.email', '=', $correo)
      ->where('galeria_vehiculo.portada', '=', 1)
      ->get();

      foreach ($consulta as $key) {
         $key->nombre;
         $key->email;
         $correo = $key->email;
      }


     $datos     = array(
        'consulta'  => $consulta,
        'correo'    => $correo     
        );

      echo $consulta;

      die();

    Mail::send('front.historial-prueba', $datos, function($message) use ($datos){
        $message
        ->to($datos['correo'])
        ->subject('Historial de productos');
    });

    echo "Los correos de mandaron correctamente";

}
```

Esta consulta funciona pero no de la manera que deseo no puedo ya que solo toma un correo y manda el historial de todos solo al primer correo **armando@prueba.com** y no me toma en cuenta los otros dos, por eso es que pensé que con un ciclo `FOR` seria una buena opción para lograr ese resultado pero no se como separar los correos y que solo me muestre uno solo

Comment: ¿Dónde está definida la variable $correos?

Comment: Es cierto, se me había pasado colocar esa línea con la cual cuento los correo que tengo dentro de mi BD, ya la coloque

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la [documentacion en laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results) , tu consulta retorna varias columnas(rows) como resultado, de la cual para acceder a cada valor individual debes hacerlo mediante un **"foreach"** dentro de tu **"for"**, ya que lo unico que haces es imprimir todo el resultado.

Entonces para acceder a cada valor deberia quedar de la siguiente manera tu código

```
<?php

     $nuevos = ContactoServicio::select('email')->distinct('email')->get();

     $array_emails = []; //declaramos el array en vacío          

     for ($i=0; $i < $correos; $i++) { 



        foreach($nuevos as $n){
           //Tomando en cuenta la estructura de la respuesta de la consulta
           //[{"email":"example@gmail.com"}] //Es un array de objetos [{}]
           echo "Correo : " . $n->email . '<br>' ;

           //Hacemos push ["a@mail.com","b@mail.com","..."]
           $array_emails[] = $n->email; 
        }

     }
     //Esto imprime 
     // Correo : example@gmail.com

     //Enviamos todos los correos :)
     Mail::send('front.historial-prueba', $datos, function($message) use ($datos){

         $message->to($array_emails)
                 ->subject('Historial de productos');
     });

     echo "Se han enviado los correos";

?>
```

Con respecto a los correos debes construir un array con todos los correos de la consulta y usar tu método para enviarlos. Existen varias maneras checalo  [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241651/error-en-un-ciclo-for/241664#241664).

Saludos!

Comment: Buenos días @frank_ivan coloque lo que tu me comentabas pero dentro de ese ciclo lo único que realiza es imprimirme los 3 correos 3 veces, pero siguiendo tu consejo hice antes del ciclo el foreach y me imprime bien los correos, pero ahora no se como lograr que el ciclo tome el primer correo y realice la primer consulta y después se siga con el segundo y así hasta terminar el ciclo  ¡Saludos y muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para ayudarme con mi duda !

Comment: Edite la respuesta para que verifiques como enviar multiples correos , saludos! @Bahamut4321